# Windows 8.1: Login on one monitor, Start/Metro on the other

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, display-settings

**PROBLEM**

I'm on Windows 8.1. I have two monitors. I'll call them A and B.

On A, I want:
 - Start/Metro screen

On B, I want:
 - Login screen

I don't care where applications spawn.

So does anyone know if I can make Windows do this? If so, how? Thanks.

**EXPLANATION**

Monitor A has a huge multi-touch screen. The monitor's support stand is far too big for the keyboard and mouse to fit in front of it, and the desk is glass so I can't get a cheap slideout tray. I like to use A with the Start/Metro screen, since the big tiles and sliding menus play nicely with multi-touch.

Monitor B has a smaller, non-touch screen. I would like to use B as my login screen since it's where my keyboard is.

Right now A is the 'primary' monitor and B is the 'secondary' monitor. This ensures that Start/Metro spawns on A. Unfortunately, it also ensures that the login screen does the same.

I'm new to Stackexchange, so I hope that I am posting in accordance with

Again, thanks for reading.

Comment: Just move the metro screen to the second monitor then restart.

Comment: If you enabled 'Show taskbar on all displays' and then  set 'Show taskbar buttons on' to 'All taskbars' the Start button will be available on both screens, so you can get metro/start screen on the big monitor by touching start button on that monitor. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi Ramhound, Supun: I'm trying to have the metro screen spawn, by default, on monitor A. At the same time, I want to use monitor B to log in. For some reason, Windows 8.1 seems to require that these both take place on the same monitor.